# How to reverse print a pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am able to print out my pattern in a shrinking method but how do I print it out in a reverse way instead so that it expands?

```
import time

pattSize = int(input("input pattern size: "))

while pattSize < 3:  
    pattSize = int(input("input pattern size: "))
    print("warning: pattern size should be at least 3!") 

if pattSize%2 == 0:
    steps = (2*(pattSize/2)) + 1;
else:
    steps = (2*((pattSize + 1) / 2))  + 1;

counter = 0
while True:
    step = (counter%steps)
    for i in range(pattSize):
        line = "";
        for j in range(pattSize):
            if (step <= 4):
                if (i == (0 + step) or j == (0 + step) ) and (i > (-1 + step) and j > (-1 + step)) and (i < (pattSize - step) and j < (pattSize - step)):
                    line += "*"
                elif (i == (pattSize - (1 + step)) or j == (pattSize - (1 +  step)) ) and (i > (-1 + step) and j > (-1 + step)) and (i < (pattSize - step) and j < (pattSize - step)):
                    line += "*"
                else:
                    line += "."

        print(line)

    counter += 1
    time.sleep(1);
```

For input of 5, the pattern shrinks as below. Now I want to reverse it, that is grow the pattern.

```
*****
*...*
*...*
*...*
*****
.....
.***.
.*.*.
.***.
.....
.....
.....
..*..
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
```

Comment: What's the pattern? what's shrinking? Please include input/output, expected output.

Comment: for example the user input is 5 it gives an output like tis :

Comment: ***  step 1
*.*
***

...   step 2
.*.
...

...  step 3
...
...

...   step 4
.*.
...

***  step 5
*.*
***

Comment: You can press the `edit` button below your question to add this to the question.

Comment: Still not clear, please explain in question what shrinking, expanding means

Comment: its an asterix box that goes from step 1 to step 3 and returns to original step 1

Comment: u can test my code on python as its abit hard to explain

Comment: expanding means it goes from small to big again

Comment: currently mine can go from big to small but i do not know how to do it          so that it can goes from small to big

Comment: I have added myself which will make it clear for everybody, but of course it could be shown.

Comment: yea tats wat i meant thks

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this. What trouble are you having with your way?

Comment: i need to reverse print the pattern =(

Comment: @JohnsonSi How is your way not working?

Comment: @PeterWood Hi it is working but i need to print the pattern to shrink from big small and grow back to big again

Comment: Yes, but what trouble are you having doing that?

Comment: i need advice on how to print it in reverse .

Comment: At the moment your counter keeps increasing so it's always growing. You could keep track of whether you should be growing or shrinking, and increase or decrease `counter` accordingly. I guess it will switch whenever `step` is zero.

Comment: I need to shrink and grow again so that it produces a dynamic effect of the box shrinking and growing continuously. So it boils down to the counter which I need to add in so that it can grow immediately after it shrinks?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Removed some unnecessary code.

1. Why are you breaking out of the while loop while looking for user input.
2. `if (step <= 4):` ?
3. There is no counter etc. required.

Code:

```
pattSize = int(input("input pattern size: "))

while pattSize < 3:  
    print("warning: pattern size should be at least 3!") 
    pattSize = int(input("input pattern size: "))

steps = int(math.ceil(pattSize/2)) 
steps = list(range(steps))

def pattern(steps):    
    for step in steps:
        for i in range(pattSize):
            line = ""
            for j in range(pattSize):
                    if (i == (0 + step) or j == (0 + step) ) and (i > (-1 + step) and j > (-1 + step)) and (i < (pattSize - step) and j < (pattSize - step)):
                        line += "*"
                    elif (i == (pattSize - (1 + step)) or j == (pattSize - (1 +  step)) ) and (i > (-1 + step) and j > (-1 + step)) and (i < (pattSize - step) and j < (pattSize - step)):
                        line += "*"
                    else:
                        line += "."

            print(line)    
        time.sleep(0.1)

while True:
    pattern(steps)
    pattern(steps[1:-1][::-1])
```

Try with size 50 it will look static and looks cool :)